# Pointer of an array item points to wrong address

Tags: c, pointers

I have 2 structs as below (which `Widget`, `Pixmap` is *XWindow* object):

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned short id;
    short valid;
    time_t mtime;
} MyEntry;

typedef struct {
    Widget shell;
    Pixmap icon;

    int nentry;
    MyEntry entry[100];
} CoverList;
```

Then I create an `CoverList` object;

```
CoverList list;
```

The problem is when I try to get `MyEntry` pointer, it always goes wrong. The address of pointer that I try to get is less than the original one 4. For example, assume that `list.entry` points to 0x500004, then `MyEntry* ent = &list.entry[0]` points to 0x500000.

```
MyEntry* ent = &list.entry[0]; // <= always wrong
```

Therefore, I cannot access anything to that object. I wonder what problem was in my code, and how to fix it?

**Update:**
I try to use 3 ways to assign that array, but all gives me wrong result:

```
MyEntry ent1 = list.entry[0];
MyEntry *ent2 = &list.entry[0];
MyEntry ent3;
memcpy(&ent3, &list.entry[0], sizeof(MyEntry));
```

Comment: *How* do you figure out the address is wrong? Because that assignment is okay for those structures.

Comment: "*The pointer that I got is less than the original one 4.*" err, please what?

Comment: I debugged my code. Assume that list.entry points to 0x500004, then `MyEntry* ent = &list.entry[0]` points to 0x500000

Comment: I think that `Widget` and `Pixmap` cause this problem, but still don't know why?

Comment: What do you expect `ent` to be assigned to? Write a small test case which is able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Seems that you didn't understand me. My expectation is every member of `ent` is as same as `list.entry[0]` member. But now it is not. And the debug give me a wrong address as I describe above

Answer (score -1):

Use brackets:

```
MyEntry* ent = &(list.entry[0]);
```

Without brackets your code looks like this for the compiler:

```
MyEntry* ent = (&list).entry[0];
```

**Edit:** Disregard what I wrote above.

Your code (with some modifications) works fine on my system:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned short id;
    short valid;
    time_t mtime;
} MyEntry;

typedef struct {
    int nentry;
    MyEntry entry[100];
} CoverList;

int main()
{
    CoverList list;
    MyEntry* ent = NULL;

    list.entry[ 0 ].id = 0;
    list.entry[ 1 ].id = 1;
    list.entry[ 2 ].id = 2;
    list.entry[ 3 ].id = 3;

    ent = &list.entry[0];

    printf("%u\n", ent->id); // prints 0

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will make no difference at all.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect - the `.` operator has higher precedence than the address of operator.